# How to use an integer array as a key of an unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map

I would like to use an integer array as a key of an unordered_map. The basic idea is that I have many different states of a problem which are represented as `int state[16]`. The values of the array are permutations of numbers from 0 to 15, like:

```
a= { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}; 
b= { 14, 1, 9, 6, 4, 8, 12, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0, 10, 11, 13, 15}; ...
```

and those will be the key in the unordered_map (the value will be a class with other stuff). How can I do that? Do I need to implement a new hash function to compare the values or I can use some provided by C++? 
My goal is using this as a hash-table, is there any other better alternative?

Comment: You probably need to implement your own specialization of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16! is approximately 2*10^13, so you can store the ordinal of the permutation in a 64-bit integer and use that as a map key, without needing to store or hash the permutation.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Numbering_permutations for the natural bijection between permutations of 0 ... N-1 and the numbers 0 ... N! - 1.

Alternatively, you could just use a `std::map`; permutations will be efficient to compare lexicographically.

A third alternative would be to use a `std::string` as the key, since your values easily fit within a `char`; `std::hash` is specialized for `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hash_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_range) from Boost.

```
namespace std
{
    template <typename T, typename A>
    struct hash<vector<T, A>>
    {
        size_t operator()(vector<T, A> const & v) const
        {
            return boost::range_hash(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
        }
    };
}
```